# Facebook API - How to get user's address, phone #?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is anyone able to get facebook user's address, phone # using FQL or Graph api?

Have tried the following FQL and was able to get 'Current City' and 'Hometown' which are under 'Basic information' but not the 'Address' or 'Phone' which are under 'Contact Information'.

`SELECT name,first_name,last_name,birthday_date,current_location,hometown_location,pic,profile_url,timezone,username,profile_update_time FROM user WHERE uid IN (xxxx)`

Answer (score 21):

These attributes are specifically and intentionally *not* available via the API, for spam prevention reasons (maybe other reasons as well)...

Comment: Facebook forum thread on this seems to be old - Does anyone know if this info is still blocked with the new graph api.  Some mobile apps include FB iphone app seem to get the user info.

Comment: @amu - Does the FB iPhone app use that API? I was under the impression their app had access to much more data than the traditional API does.

Comment: Does this still stand true as of today? It is publicly listed on [their API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user) but I'm not sure if it is dependent on other factors.

Answer (score 11):

Facebook did make a <strike>[blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446)</strike> that phone number and address fields were available by prompting for user_address and user_mobile_phone extended permissions in Jan 2011, but they since removed those permissions.

The phone fql fields are "cell" and "other_phone" but your application needs to be whitelisted to access them.

Comment: How can my application get in white list?

Answer (score 0):

I found phone_number in their recent documentation, but Facebook has didn't mention it anywhere else. Might be they are planning to introduce in their updates.

Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

```
// Add the properties particular to the type restaurant.restaurant
restaurant[@"restaurant"] = @{@"category": @[@"Mexican"],
                 @"contact_info": @{@"street_address": @"123 Some st",
                                    @"locality": @"Menlo Park",
                                    @"region": @"CA",
                                    @"phone_number": @"555-555-555",
                                    @"website": @"http://www.example.com"}};
```

You can see @"phone_number": @"555-555-555" in the code.

Comment: That's for businesses' `pages` - different fields than `users` have.