# Is it possible now to get through Facebook API user's address?

Tags: facebook

I found this [Facebook API - How to get user's address, phone #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone) ,but this was last year. I would like to know if now is there any way I can get the user address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question of [Facebook API - How to get user's address, phone #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone).  The answer is still the same, that the user's address and phone number is not available via the api.  At one point Facebook posted a [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446) about how to get address/phone information and did temporarily enable access to this info, but I'm pretty sure they have since revoked that and said they would review that possibility later.