# How to fetch user's mobile number from facebook?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-socialauth

I am using **django-social_auth** to make users register and login via **facebook**. I want to access the **phone number** of the user.

Tried searching on google and stackoverflow , but didn't find any answer. Searched the facebook docs as well. There I found that there used to be permission for **'user_mobile_phone'** but it has been removed.

It was also written than now it will be provided with basic permissions but it wasn't available(what I found). 
I tried using **Graph API**, but was unsuccessful.

So, Someone please tell me the way ,if there is any, to get user data.

EDIT:17 June 2014 -

Is this possible now to get User's Mobile number via the Graph API ?

Comment: No, you can not access a user’s mobile number via the API.

Comment: @JoSo, i think he wrote what he tried.

Comment: The phone is not available throw the API. Take a look at [this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone

Comment: Doesn't look like it is exposed by facebook api, unless you are a signed business partner. In your app, ask the user for phone number post authentication. More reliable, obvious and non-spam way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API does not let you access the user's contact number. You will have to request the user's contact details manually using a form.