# Getting Facebook friend's phone and email

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API - How to get user’s address, phone #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone)

Is it possible to get friend's phone number and email if the user grant permission to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide Facebook friend's phone and email under privacy policy.

All you can get from yourself or your friend is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/).