# Facebook Api getting phone or mobile number?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API - How to get user’s address, phone #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone)

Is it still possible to get the user Phone or Mobile number using Graph Api? I already read a lot of forum regarding this issue and the other said the facebook removed the permission to get the mobile or phone number.

So I just asking if there is someone can tell if there is still way to get it?

any thought will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A pretty scary feature. 
It seems that Facebook has retracted these features of the API due to privacy concerns.
For more details read [this](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have the same issue when i am trying with facebook.I read lots of forums but no use.I came to know it is not possible to get the `"Phone no"`.But instead of that i took `"mail id"` and `"user name"` and i managed with that..